# Adding description to product attribute taxonomy page

Tags: woocommerce

Is it possible to add a new field in this page `/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=product&page=product_attributes`, but not to terms? When creating new taxonomy `pa_something` I want to add description to this.

[image]